# How to do an outer join into a list while joining a third table

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq

I have 3 tables: table A, B and C. Table A has primary key "Id", both table B and C link to this table by storing the id in a FK member.

I want the following:

For every row in table A, get the matching row in table B (the Id of A equals the FK of table B) and also get every row in table C that has FK = Id.

So my result should be a list of:

```
{
     TableARow,
     TableBRow,
     List<TableCRow>
}

var query = from r in context.TableA
        join c in context.TableB
        on r.Id equals c.FK
        join m in context.TableC
        on r.Id equals m.FK
        into mappings
        select new MyViewModel
        {
             A = r,
             B = c,
             C = mappings.ToList()
         };

var result = query.ToList();
```

The query above is what I have but it only returns one item every time for mappings.ToList().

Many thanks

Comment: Instead of using joins why not use the navigation properties of the entities?  https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/

Answer (score 0):

When you `join` your different tables the way you did your model would look something like `{ TableARow, TableBRow, TableCRow }`.

If instead you want to have it that `TableCRow` is within a `List` you should `GroupBy` the `A` and `B` rows:

```
var query = (from r in context.TableA
        join c in context.TableB
        on r.Id equals c.FK
        join m in context.TableC
        on r.Id equals m.FK

        group m by new { r, c } into grouping

        select new MyViewModel
        {
             A = grouping.Key.r,
             B = grouping.Key.c,
             C = grouping.ToList()
         }).ToList();
```